# Redux toolkit persist, My authentication is not persisted react-native expo

Tags: react-native, redux

So I have looked through this site and I have come across interesting questions post that I have implemented and have no results. So please have a look at the code and direct me. This is what my store looks like and please bear in mind that I am using a package called `reduxjs-toolkit-persist`

```
import { configureStore } from "@reduxjs/toolkit";
import AsyncStorage from "@react-native-async-storage/async-storage";
import {
  persistCombineReducers,
  persistStore,
  FLUSH,
  REHYDRATE,
  PAUSE,
  PERSIST,
  PURGE,
  REGISTER,
} from "reduxjs-toolkit-persist";
import authSlice from "./authSlice";
import userSlice from "./userSlice";

const persistConfig = {
  key: "root",
  storage: AsyncStorage,
  whitelist: ["authUser", "loginUser"],
};
const _persistedReducer = persistCombineReducers(persistConfig, {
  auth: authSlice,
  user: userSlice,
});
const store = configureStore({
  reducer: { _persistedReducer },
  middleware: (getDefaultMiddleware) =>
    getDefaultMiddleware({
      serializableCheck: {
        ignoredActions: [FLUSH, REHYDRATE, PAUSE, PERSIST, PURGE, REGISTER],
      },
      serializableCheck: false,
    }),
});
export const persistor = persistStore(store);
export default store;
```

and this is what my `app.js` looks like

```
import { StatusBar } from "expo-status-bar";
import { Router } from "./src/navigation/router";
import { Provider } from "react-redux";
import store, { persistor } from "./src/store";
import { LogBox } from "react-native";
import { PersistGate } from "reduxjs-toolkit-persist/integration/react";

LogBox.ignoreLogs([
  "AsyncStorage has been extracted from react-native core and will be removed in a future release.",
]);
export default function App() {
  return (
    <Provider store={store}>
      <PersistGate loading={null} persistor={persistor}>
        <Router />
      </PersistGate>
      <StatusBar style="auto" animated />
    </Provider>
  );
}
```

I have followed the documentation but I don't get desired results. I don't know if it is storage problem or a middleware problem

Comment: What is your aim? Persisting authentication ? @code46

Comment: Yes please.. I have made everything I see in the docs but my authentication is not persisting

Comment: If you want to persist only authentication but nothing else, using `redux-persist` would be overkill for only this purpose. I would suggest using `react-native-async-storage` or any other storage libraries for persisting authentication.

Comment: @Tarik Thank you for your response. I will be relying on reduxjs-toolkit-persist for other things I currently don't know of right now. I am taking an online course for javascript and this is our semester project. So I need this to work so that other task for for the package at hand will be smooth for me. Please look at it and assist